# Multiline regular expression not matching

Tags: .net, regex

I have a regular expression to get all the data in between HTML comments. Below is my regex and my HTML part.

```
Dim rgx As New Regex("<!-- START data-contentid='([0-9]+)' -->((\s|.)*?)<!-- END data-contentid='([0-9]+)' -->", RegexOptions.Multiline Or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

This Regex is working, it will return 2 results with the desired groups. The strange part is this:

If I change this: `((\s|.)*?)` to this `(.*?)` my regex stops working, while the `.` stands for any character.

Any clue in why the OR regex is working but why this DOT regex is not?

```
<!-- START data-contentid='1151' -->
<div class="dyn-content content" data-contentid="1151">
The content

</div>
<!-- END data-contentid='1151' --><br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
    AABB
<!-- START data-contentid='866' -->
<div class="dyn-content content" data-contentid="866">
    <h1></h1>
    ASBCSDFGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG</div>
<!-- END data-contentid='866' -->
```

Comment: have you tried looking at your regex with [regexper](http://www.regexper.com/)?

Comment: It says `white-space` or `any character`, so theoretically I don't need the `white-space`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RegexOptions.Multiline` makes the regex match line per line.

You meant `RegexOptions.SingleLine`.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx):

> Multiline mode. Changes the meaning of ^ and $ so they match **at the beginning and end, respectively, of any line**, and not just the beginning and end of the entire string.

Comment: Ah my interpertation was wrong for the multiline, I thought it would mean my regex can be spread over multiple lines.